# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int - same syntax as an array that works?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays, both as `int` types. The `costs[]` array works perfectly, without errors or bugs, but the `stands` array, which is coded exactly the same, gives the error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int" in a method I define near the bottom of the program called `buttonFunc`. In the `init()` method, I call `stands[1] = 0` and that works fine, but when I do nearly the same thing (replacing the 1 with an integer defined when you call the method), it gives me the error. Why is it that two arrays, exactly the same in syntax and usage, can do this?

```
`import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    double money = 0;
    double income = 2; //Actual income is this * 0.4
    //int lemonadeStands = 0;
    int cookieStands = 0;
    int cupcakeStands = 0;
    int cookieCost = 25;
    int cupcakeCost = 75;
    int modifier = 1;

    int[] costs = new int[3];
    int[] stands = new int[3];              //Declaring the array - same as the costs[] array, but it doesn't work?

    Button buyLemonade;
    Button buyCookie;
    Button buyCupcake;

    int time = 0;
    int timeComparison = (int) (Math.random()*50 + 120);

    private Graphics dBufferedGraphic = null;
    private Image dbufferedImage = null;

    public void init() {
        costs[1] = 10;
        stands[1] = 0;                  //No error here?

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buyLemonade = new Button("Buy a Lemonade Stand");
        buyCookie = new Button("Buy a Cookie Stand");
        buyCupcake = new Button("Buy a Cupcake Stand");

        add(buyLemonade);
        add(buyCookie);
        add(buyCupcake);

        buyLemonade.addActionListener(this);
        buyCookie.addActionListener(this);
        buyCupcake.addActionListener(this);

        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        g.drawString("Money: $" + df.format(money), 10, 10);
        g.drawString("Income: $" + income / 2.5 + " per second", 10, 24);
        g.drawString("Lemonade Stands: " + stands[1], 10, 52);
        g.drawString("Cookie Stands: " + cookieStands, 10, 66);
        g.drawString("Cupcake Stands: " + cupcakeStands, 10, 80);
        g.drawString("Cost: " + costs[1], 355, 40);
        g.drawString("Cost: " + cookieCost, 495, 40);
        g.drawString("Cost: " + cupcakeCost, 620, 40);
    }

    public void run() {}
    public void start() {}
    public void stop() {}
    public void destroy() {}

    Timer t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            money += income / 50; //0.8 per second
            repaint();
        }
     });

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /*if(e.getSource() == buyLemonade) {
            if (money >= lemonadeCost) {
            System.out.println("Lemonade stand bought. ");
            income += 1; //0.4 actual
            lemonadeStands++;
            money -= lemonadeCost;                      Replacing with method.
            lemonadeCost += 4 * modifier; 
            modifier++;
            }else System.out.println("Not enough money! ");
        }*/
        buttonFunc(costs[1], 1, stands[1], 1, "Lemonade stand", 1);
        if(e.getSource() == buyCookie) {
            if (money >= cookieCost) {
            System.out.println("Cookie stand bought. ");
            income += 3;
            cookieStands++;
            money -= cookieCost;
            cookieCost += 8 * modifier;
            modifier += 2;
            }else System.out.println("Not enough money! ");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == buyCupcake) {
            if (money >= cupcakeCost) {
            System.out.println("Cupcake stand bought. ");
            income += 6;
            cupcakeStands++;
            money -= cupcakeCost;
            cupcakeCost += 18 * modifier;
            modifier += 3;
            }else System.out.println("Not enough money! ");
        }
    }

    public void buttonFunc(int cost, int incomeProduced, int stands, int modifierAmount, String name, int arrayLocation) {
        if (money >= cost) {
            System.out.println(name + " bought. ");
            income += incomeProduced;
            stands[arrayLocation] += 1;                 //Where I get the error
            money -= cost;
            costs[arrayLocation] = (int) (costs[arrayLocation]  + costs[arrayLocation] * 0.4);
            modifier += modifierAmount;
        }else System.out.println("Not enough money! ");
    }

    public void update (Graphics g) {
        if (dbufferedImage == null) {
                dbufferedImage = createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
                dBufferedGraphic = dbufferedImage.getGraphics ();
            }
          dBufferedGraphic.setColor(getBackground ());
          dBufferedGraphic.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

          dBufferedGraphic.setColor(getForeground());
          paint(dBufferedGraphic);

          g.drawImage(dbufferedImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a formal parameter with the name `stands` in your method, which hides the array name. So, in your method `stands` is refering to the formal parameter, which is an `int`, and that is why the error.

Either change your formal parameter name, or use `this` to refer to the instance array type field `stands`:

```
this.stands[arrayLocation] += 1;
```

Also, it seems like you are not even using the `stands` parameter in your method. If you intended to pass the array there, then change your method signature to:

```
public void buttonFunc(int cost, int incomeProduced, int[] stands, ...)
```

and then invoke this method as:

```
buttonFunc(costs[1], 1, stands, 1, "Lemonade stand", 1);  // Change stands[1] to stands
```

You can also remove that method parameter completely. Since `stands` is an instance reference variable, you can access it from any instance method. Also, modifying the value in any array index will be reflected for the actual array object. So, just get rid of the `stands` parameter. It will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing stands[1] , which is an int value and not an array reference.Also you are accepting an int value and not an array in your method `buttonFunc` declaration:

```
public void buttonFunc(int cost, int incomeProduced, int stands, int modifierAmount, String name, int arrayLocation)
```

As stands is an `int` so accessing it in an `array` form will lead to error in the line:

```
        stands[arrayLocation] += 1;                 //Where I get the error
```

Also you seems to be confused between method param `cost` and `costs` array defined on class level.

Comment: Why is it that there is no problem with the `costs` array, then?

Comment: @IHazABone You are getting confused between 'costs' the global array and the method input param 'cost'.